# Returning Data with axios caused an asychrunous problem when pushing in array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, axios

I tried to get some information from some APIs with looping on an array to get array of results from axios get the information didn't pushed to resultat array correctly I think it's an async problem because when I use setTimeout in component that call the array it shows the data correctly and when not using setTimeout it shows the array corrctly but can't access their values
could you plz help me to make my function of getting the information async or give me another solution

The problem is caused by foreach loop maybee promise can solve the problem 
the code is

```
const orgName = org.value.substr(1);
  const groups = user.group.filter(group => group.includes(orgName));
  const resultat = [];
  dispatch(SharingLoading());
  groups.forEach(function(group, index) {
    let idparts = group.split("#");
    let aBox = "a" + orgName;
    axios
      .get("api/" + aBox + "/group/" + aBox + ":" + idparts[1])
      .then(res => resultat.push(res.data[0]));
  });
  dispatch(setSharing(resultat));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const orgName = "a" + org.value.substr(1);
let groups = user.group.filter(group => group.includes(orgName));
groups = groups.map(group => group.split("#")[1])
const resultat = [];
dispatch(SharingLoading());


Promise.all(groups.map(group =>
    axios
        .get("api/" + orgName + "/group/" + orgName + ":" + group)
        .then((response) => resultat.push(response.data[0]))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err) // dispatch action for error handling
        })
))
    .then(() => {
        dispatch(setSharing(resultat));
    })
```

Comment: it said can't use keyword await outside async function

Answer (score 0):

```
const orgName = org.value.substr(1);
const groups = user.group.filter(group => group.includes(orgName));
dispatch(SharingLoading());
Promise.all(groups.map(group => {
  let idparts = group.split("#");
  let aBox = "a" + orgName;
  return axios
    .get("api/" + aBox + "/group/" + aBox + ":" + idparts[1])
})).then(list => list.map(res => res.data[0]))
.then(resultat => dispatch(setSharing(resultat)));
```